# Trigger compilation error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, error-handling, datatrigger

I need some help in creating a trigger.

```
create or replace trigger trigger_one 
before insert on Funtom_timesheet
for each row
Declare
V_id    number;
V_hours number;
Begin
Select max(timesheet_ID)+1 into v_id from Funtom_timesheet
:new.timesheet_ID :=v_id;
select grade_hours into V_hours
from funtom_grade join funtom_employee
on emp_grade = grade_id
where empid = :new.timesheet_emp;
if V_hours >:new.timesheet_hours
else
:new.timesheet_overtime :=
:new.timesheet_hours-V_hours
:new.timesheet_hours:= V_hours;
END IF;
END;
/
```

please tell me which part of my code is wrong so I could work on it,
Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Or what is the issue?

Comment: look at Janis's answer. Please try to solve the issue yourself, as this is a syntactical issue

Comment: I have posted this question in this thread for you guys to help me out, can you guy please tell me where the syntax errors are exactly, thanks

Comment: What client tool are you using? If SQL*Plus, compile the trigger and then type _show errors_ to get the specific errors. Method to get errors will probably vary by client.

Comment: LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
16/5     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TIMESHEET_OVERTIME'

Comment: Is there a timesheet_overtime column in the  funtom_timesheet  table?

Comment: thanks a lot bruv I appreciate all your help.

Comment: IT finally worked, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many syntax errors - missing `;` and `then`. There can't be `if` only with `else` part and without expression on it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_ONE
  BEFORE INSERT ON FUNTOM_TIMESHEET
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_ID    NUMBER;
  V_HOURS NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(TIMESHEET_ID) + 1 INTO V_ID FROM FUNTOM_TIMESHEET;
  :NEW.TIMESHEET_ID := V_ID;
  SELECT GRADE_HOURS
    INTO V_HOURS
    FROM FUNTOM_GRADE
    JOIN FUNTOM_EMPLOYEE
      ON EMP_GRADE = GRADE_ID
   WHERE EMPID = :NEW.TIMESHEET_EMP;
  IF V_HOURS > :NEW.TIMESHEET_HOURS THEN
    NULL;
  ELSE
    :NEW.TIMESHEET_OVERTIME := :NEW.TIMESHEET_HOURS - V_HOURS;
    :NEW.TIMESHEET_HOURS    := V_HOURS;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Also better use SEQUENCES instead of:

```
SELECT MAX(TIMESHEET_ID) + 1 INTO V_ID FROM FUNTOM_TIMESHEET;
:NEW.TIMESHEET_ID := V_ID;
```

When selecting form the same table as inserting, you can get *MUTATING trigger* error (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm)

Comment: can you please tell me the errors, because I don't know where they are exactly that's why I posted this question.

Comment: the error is  bad bind variable 'NEW.TIMESHEET_OVERTIME'

Comment: Does table FUNTOM_TIMESHEET contains column TIMESHEET_OVERTIME?
If yes, then you can try to add `REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW` before `FOR EACH ROW`